# How to pass parameters in Rails routes helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I know how to pass parameters the dumb way. For example,

```
<%= link_to "Order", new_order_item_path(:item_id => @item.id) %>
```

The OrderItemsController receives it as `params[:item_id] = id`.

Problem:

```
@order_item = OrderItem.new(params)
```

raises an exception (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: action, controller).  I can get around this with the following code.

```
@order_item = OrderItem.new
@order_item.item_id = params[:item_id]
```

I know the controller requires `params[:order_item][:item_id]` for new to work the first way.  My question is, how do I get `new_order_item_path` to generate url?  I know this isn't a major problem, but it just bugs me that I don't know the cleaner/proper way to do this.  I have tried searching, but only received unrelated questions/answers/results.

Thanks

Comment: 10 seconds after click ask I realized that new_order_item_path(:order_item => { :item_id => @item.id }) works.  It feels a bit cludgy, but it works.

Comment: you should post that as an answer an accept it, I ran also on this problem, can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify if you didn't want to use it or not, but in your model, you could make the attribute item_id accessible like so:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :item_id
...
```

In this way,

```
@order_item = OrderItem.new(params)
```

would work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# Controller
def get_item_edit_method
  @order = OrderItem.find("your criteria")
  #@order = OrderItem.new # if new
  @item = Item.new() 
end

def post_item_edit_method
  @order = OrderItem.new(params) # should work now
  @order.save
end
# End controller

<!-- view -->
<% @order.item = @item %>
<%= link_to "Order", new_order_item_path(@order) %>
<!-- end view -->
```